# NSCalendar date error when converting to Hijri Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

While converting a **Gregorian** calendar date to **Hijri** calendar date, it's one day behind  if we use `NSIslamicCalendar` and one day ahead when we use `NSIslamicCivilCalendar`.

I use below code for conversion:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [timeStampValue doubleValue];
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds]; 
NSCalendar *islamicCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];  
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setCalendar:islamicCalendar];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
dateFormatter.locale =[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_SA"];
NSString * islamicDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:thisDate];
```

**UPDATE**

I will add more details to the questions with examples.

*First I have tried with NSIslamicCalendar:*

We got the NSDate: **2014-06-17 14:00:04 +0000**

After converting to NSIslamicCalendar: **Tuesday, Shaʻban 20, 1435 AH**

Correct date: **Tuesday, Shaʻban 19, 1435 AH**

*with NSIslamicCivilCalendar:*

We got the NSDate: **2014-06-17 14:00:04 +0000**

After converting to NSIslamicCivilCalendar: **Tuesday, Shaʻban 18, 1435 AH**

Correct date: **Tuesday, Shaʻban 19, 1435 AH**

Please help us to fix this problem.

Comment: What is the date you are getting and what is the date you are expecting and why?  It seems like this conversion is pretty complicated (days start at sunset, etc?)

Comment: I have added some more details to the question.

Comment: From my limited research it seems that Sha'ban 20 would start at sunset on June 17th.  Is that right? What time zone are you doing this calculation from?

Comment: We are using epoch value to get the date. I think epoch value will always be in UTC/GMT.

Comment: A date is a date, the time zone information in the date is only relevant once you convert it to a string.  Just for fun, try an earlier value like June 17, 2014 00:00:00 +0000 and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that and I am getting the result as  Tue,18 Shaʻban 1435 05:30:00 +0530

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55831/discussion-between-shaan-and-borrrden).

Comment: Try using NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicTabular..

Answer (score 1):

Salam. There is nothing wrong with the API. Please refer to this thread for an explanation.

[NSIslamicCalendar and NSIslamicCivilCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893442/nsislamiccalendar-and-nsislamiccivilcalendar)

You need to choose which type of Islamic Calendar to use. Essentially, the hijri is based on moon sightings and therefore most prayer apps include a manual correction to allow the user to update the date should the date be incorrect.

The API is simply a predictive calendar when it comes to the hijri.

Comment: Do you know how to add day correction for hijri calendar?